# Reinstall windows legally - HP laptop

Tags: windows-7, laptop, reinstall

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where do I download Windows 7 (legally from Microsoft)?](https://superuser.com/questions/78761/where-do-i-download-windows-7-legally-from-microsoft)

I recently bought a new HP laptop with windows 7 home premium x64 and as many of you know, HP is horrible when it comes to preinstalled bloatware so I'd like to wipe everything clean and install a fresh copy of windows 7 home premium x64.

The problem is that the laptop did not ship with windows installation DVD.
So, where can get the windows setup **legally**?
I mean, I already have the key on the windows genuine sticker on my laptop. I just need to obtain the setup **legally**.

Comment: i guess usually we can activate any copy of your windows through the given serial number

Comment: I wasn't aware it was illegal to download a plain old .iso of the original installation disk, provided you're using the valid license key you bought with your laptop, why should they care? Dell published links to download all versions directly. http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/software-os/w/microsoft_os/3316.2-1-microsoft-windows-7-official-iso-download-links-digital-river.aspx

Comment: @Anonymous - Its not illegal.

Comment: @Ramhound - Ah right, that would make sense. :-)

Comment: apologies...but the duplicate question was not suggested when I created my question..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are legally entitled to reinstall your windows installation if you have a key you bought. In this case you bought it with your laptop. Although you cannot install a different OS legally until you have a key. Keep in mind you can only activate 5 times before you have to call microsoft.

Download Link:  http://www.mydigitallife.info/windows-7-iso-x86-and-x64-official-direct-download-links-ultimate-professional-and-home-premium/.

Edit: This link will give you SP1 with the disc, so less updating:  http://www.mydigitallife.info/official-windows-7-sp1-iso-from-digital-river/

Comment: There is a better link from that site which lets you download the Service Pack 1 version of Windows (less updates to run): http://www.mydigitallife.info/official-windows-7-sp1-iso-from-digital-river/

Answer (score 2):

This provides links to ISO's . Please note, these are **NOT** tested by myself but appear to be genuine.

http://www.pcworld.com/article/248995/how_to_install_windows_7_without_the_disc.html

You could always ask to borrow a friends copy and use that.

Comment: This is just an article with the same link as Wolfo's link.

Comment: But my link was posted first

Comment: Mine actually has an explanation

Comment: I never said mine was the better answer! I just replied to Ramhound and correctly pointed out that my answer was posted first.